# How to Debug WordPress theme with PHPStorm

Tags: php, wordpress, phpstorm

I've installed PHPStorm (8) and trying to debug WordPress theme using xDebug. I tried chrome browser extension and some other settings in the PHP Storm settings.

I've searched a lot but still unable to attach the page to the debugger. What I want is to run the code line by line and check variables etc.

Can someone tell me what exactly is required so the debugging works?

I've following structure:

```
WAMP is at:  c:\wamp

Project is:  d:\projects\test

alias is: http://localhost/test/
```

When I opened the project in PHP Storm. It identified it as WordPress project. But it never attaches the browser to debugger.

**Edit**
Here is the related xDebug code in php.ini

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.3-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

I also tried `true` instead of `1`. Also tried without providing any port.

Comment: show us your php.ini xdebug section.

Comment: just do it oldschoolisch and echo the vars dircetly to the page and exit the script after that, or for arrays, use `print_r($ar,true)` in a `<pre>`-tag... never needed xdebug for debugging

Comment: While I agree adding debug output / log statements works in a pinch, a proper debugger is a lot more convenient.

Comment: I know that this is a really old question. If someone is looking for an easiest way to debug WordPress, hope this will help. I have written an article for an easy way to debug WordPress. Find the below link.
https://digitecz.com/web-development/how-to-debug-wordpress-using-browsers-javascript-console/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be a lot of ways to set up debugging. There are browser plugins, and bookmark commands, and all sorts of elaborate setups.

For the most part, I always want debugging enabled while I'm developing. If that's true for you, you might consider adding this to your php.ini file:

```
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

In addition, a key part to my setup is that I have to click the button in the toolbar for "*Start Listening for PHP Debug Connections*", and keep this enabled while I work. This is also in the menus under "Run".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried zero-configuration guide for PhpStorm debugger?
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm

I'm using this solution and it works fine.

Don't forget to add breakpoints and I recommend to create the bookmarklets to activate/deactivate debugger cookies in browser (https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/).